# Why does this code output consecutive numbers?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to post a basic `JS` trick question, and it's apparently tricking me too :)

Run this in your console:

```
x = (w) => w.length;
setTimeout(console.log(x), 0);
```

The, each time you run `setTimeout(console.log(x), 0);` you get an increasing number. Why is that? Shouldn't the `w` parameter referrer to the `window` object?

Comment: That looks like it increments w. Simplified `let x = w+w`

Comment: @zer00ne But `w` is not a variable, it's just a parameter referring to some other variable. Probably the `window` object. Why would calling the function increase anything?

Comment: @self What context? This is all the code, run it in your browser console in a new tab.

Comment: like self is saying, `setTimeout` returns a value which is reflected in console. I would've never have experienced such an issue, I have a tendency to declare all vars upfront overzealously.

Comment: @zer00ne All vars are declared correctly in the code above, you can declare `x` with `var` if you want. The problem is that in the console output I confused the `setTimeout` return value for the value that I was expecting from the `log` function

Comment: My bad, I meant declare and assign value.

Comment: This isn't working for me in Node, at least - complains that the first arg passed to `setTimeout` is not a function. am I missing something? I'm guessing the increasing number is the number of the timeout in your REPL.

Comment: @DanPantry that's becaused the `undefined` value isn't a function. console.log returns undefined, most likely the browser runtime is just ignoring the fact that it isn't a function

Comment: That's what I thought, weird

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`setTimout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) returns a value. You're seeing the timer id which is the returned value of setTimeout, which can used as the argument to a [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) call.

> The returned timeoutID is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies
>   the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be
>   passed to Window.clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout. [0]

[0] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

The `w` parameter would not refer to the window object. console.log returns undefined, so your function would never get called.

Comment: Oh my God, you are right. I always thought that was the logged value, I was ignoring the `function...` log in the console which was actually logging the `x` function. :)

Comment: Tbh, this was actually pretty hard to notice, great bug-spotting techniques you got there :D

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: @Cristy I would encourage you to accept my answer :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot :D